# ActiveRecord query, joins (Rails 3.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How would I go about getting a JSON object with

```
[
  {
    Property.field_1,
    Property.field_n,
    PropAssignmConsumer.field_1,
    PropAssignmConsumer.field_n
  },
  {
    Property.field_1,
    Property.field_n,
    PropAssignmConsumer.field_1,
    PropAssignmConsumer.field_n
  },
  ...,
  {
    Property.field_1,
    Property.field_n,
    PropAssignmConsumer.field_1,
    PropAssignmConsumer.field_n
  }
]
```

sorted by some key (can be a field in either Property or PropAssignmConsumer) for a given user_entity object?  i.e. get all properties linked to a given consumer/user_entity, extracting fields from both properties and prop_assignm_consumers, sorting by a field in the properties or prop_assignm_consumer table.

These are my models:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :prop_assignm_consumers,  :dependent => :restrict
end

class PropAssignmConsumer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :consumer
  belongs_to  :property
end

class Consumer < UserEntity
  has_many        :prop_assignm_consumers,    :dependent => :destroy
  has_many        :properties,                :through   => :prop_assignm_consumers
end
```

I am currently doing

```
properties = user_entity.properties.find(:all, :order => "#{sort_key} #{sort_ord}")
properties.each do |p|
  a = p.prop_assignm_consumers.find_by_consumer_id(current_user.user_entity.id)
  ... do something with a and p....
end
```

but this seems inefficient....

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something.  Why doesn't your property also reference consumers?  You have many to many, you just didn't complete it.  Just adding `has_many :consumers, :through => :prop_assignm_consumer` would then let you do

```
properties = user_entity_properties.all(:include => :consumers)
properties.each do |p| 
  p.consumers.where(:id => current_user.user_entity.id)
end
```

Though now that we write that, and given that you're doing find_by and not find_all_by, it's pretty clear there's going to be only 1.  So you can go the other way.

```
consumer = Consumer.where(:id => current_user.user_entity.id).includes(:properties).first
consumer.properties.each do |p| 
  ... do something with p and consumer
end
```

ref
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html